# require a dojo module in angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, dojo

I am importing a Dojo module into an Angular project. I installed Dojo, Dijit and Dojox under `node_modules` of the project, as well as dojo-typings. In the typescript file `dojo/parser` is used something like this:

```
import * as parser from 'dojo/parser'
```

But the compiling always throws an error:

```
Error: ./node_modules/dojo/on.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dom-addeventlistener?:./aspect' in 'node_modules/dojo'

"./has!dom-addeventlistener?:./aspect" is required in on.js, looks it did not recognize the has plugin and conditional loading.
```

I also tried to add the reference path for `loader.d.ts` in the ts file and use

```
require('dojo/parser')
```

but the error persisted.

Anyone experience similar problem and know how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: did you load dojo/dojo.js in your index.html, along with a dojoconfig to configure where the dojo files are located?

Comment: I added "node_modules/dojo/dojo.js" in scripts in angular.json, so this should be loaded when the app starts up?? I also added dojoConfig in index.html.

Comment: does it work if you do dojo.version in the console? if you can post your dojo config code. dojo.js must be loaded after config.